Weird pass-transistor MUX circuit

I found the following circuit in my FPGA course. The course claims it is a multiplexer (presumably \$4\$ inputs), but offers no further explanations about how it works.
I can see that \$S_a\$ selects one of \$A_0\$ and \$A_1\$, and \$S_b\$ selects one of \$B_0\$ and \$B_1\$.
I don't understand what the second level of the circuit is supposed to do. Why are the 2 lower transistors all by themselves, without any 'control pin'? I have no idea if the transistors are meant to be n-channel or p-channel, and my transistor knowledge is pretty shaky either way. Are there 2 transistors from the \$B_0\$, \$S_b\$, \$B_1\$ side supposed to somehow overpower the transistor at the end of the XNOR? Or are \$S_0\$ and \$S_1\$ meant to connect to those transistors as well?
I'm also confused as to why would a 4 input multiplexer have 4 selection inputs? Has anybody seen this kind of circuit before, and could maybe shed some light on how it works? Thank you!

If either $S_0$ or $S_1$ or both are active the lower section ($B_x$) is forwarded. If both are inactive then the upper section ($A_x$) is forwarded. However, we are missing some context (probably because you are and cannot pass it along.)

Are your course notes available on line?

They are not online, and only half of it is in English. It is a slide that says "LE MUX-design used in antifuse FPGAs", with the picture above next to it. LE stands for Logic Element. The course notes are all over the place, unfortunately

I'm wondering whether this is meant to be a representation of the original Actel (now Microchip) basic logic module, which is usually drawn like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
See Figure 2 in the Act-1 datasheet

This could be it. Actel Act-1 is mentioned in passing some pages ago. I just realized I mistook the OR gate for an XOR somehow. The design makes a bit more sense with an OR there. Thank you!

S0 and S1 are connected to those transistors' gates. The lines are then continued without a dot. (This way of drawing is sometimes used  when there are multple transistors with connectes gates/bases near each other; you would typically see this in opamps that have multiple current sources to supply multiple subcircuits. But in this case, it's rather misleading.)
This circuit definitely is weird. I see no reason why S0 and S1 are separate, or why Sa and Sb are separate.
You do understand how muxes work, and your questions are reasonable.
Sometimes, students are given weird circuits that would not make sense in practice in order to check whether they have understood the basic principles and can reverse engineer the behaviour. In any case, whoever gave you this course is, I assume, being paid to answer such questions.

I think you're right, the design seems to work if $S_0$ and $S_1$ are connected like that. Most of my confusion came from somehow mistaking the OR gate for an XOR.
